# multiple inbound files in single flow in mule 3.3

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I have a situation where a big (100 mb) CSV file is placed at a location on FTP server. 
The sending party notifies about complete transmission of file using a small(1kb) .complete file. 
I want my flow to trigger when .complete file is placed. but as soon as .complete file is placed, i want to FTP GET the CSV as well. 
I found that i cannot have 2 inbound endpoints in one single mule flow. how is it then possible to read multiple inbound data sources in a single flow in mule?
If for example, someone has to read two different files and construct an output file based on the input of the previous two, how can that be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to write a custom component within your flow to retrieve the csv from the ftp server. You can use the run method of the [FtpMessageReceiver](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.x/transports/ftp/src/main/java/org/mule/transport/ftp/FtpMessageReceiver.java?source=c) code as an example for your component

Answer (score 0):

It should work with the FTP connector, but only if you use it as a "source"/inbound endpoint (first element of your flow). 
Check out the docs

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/ftp-connector